# What does "come in" mean in the following context?

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs

1. where does the Pro in iPad Pro come in?
2. Microphones come in an assortment of configurations to meet a variety of uses.

Does it means to function as some kind of contributor? Or does it mean to become available or be usable?

Comment: The second...”come in an assortment” means that are available in an assortment.

Comment: In the first case it means "what is the position of the syllable in the name". I can't really see why that question would be asked in that case. The question I might ask would be "Where does the Pro in iPro come _from_?" In the second case it means "exist" or "are available". For instance "This model of car comes in five different colours and three trim levels but Model T Fords only came in black."

Comment: Sorry for a dumb question. But because it's literally quoted from a tech review YouTube video.

Answer (score 1):

In "1" the meaning  is that of a phrasal verb and it is given in the SOED as follows.

> (SOED) (***q***) be (*useful, etc.*) as something to have available

Here, the adjective wouldn't be "useful" but something as "explanatory".

- What is  the "Pro"  explanatory of in "iPad Pro" (as something to have available)? (*I believe that "as something to have available" can be omitted, thus the parentheses.*)

In "2" it is as follows; the verb is not reckoned with as a phrasal verb, it is just a regular verb.

> (SOED) **6b** Of a thing: be available or on sale (*in* a size, colour, etc. or with certain features etc.). Mid 20th century

This latter definition is confirmed in  [OALD, 11](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/come_1?q=come).

> ​  [intransitive] (not used in the progressive tenses)
> (of goods, products, etc.) to be available or to exist in a particular way
> **come in something** This dress comes in black and red.
> **come with something** The DVD comes with several bonus features.
>
> - adj. (informal)
>   New cars don't come cheap (= they are expensive).

- Microphones are available  in an assortment of configurations to meet a variety of uses.

Comment: Answer of Sentence 1 is exactly what I expected and corresponds to Merriam Webster explanation ": to function in an indicated manner". Think I've got a hang of it. So appreciate it.

Comment: The general construction *Where does X **come in** [regarding Y]?* is a loose "container metaphor" usage equivalent to ***In what way / How** [does X relate to Y?]* or *[...is X part of Y]?*

Comment: What is the "SOED"?

Comment: @AlMaki This is explained to some length [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/349876/lph?tab=profile).

Comment: "That brightness as perceived by you would be my luminance and be measured in Nits." And  I encountered it once again.